# How to retrieve the data on selection of a cell from a custom UITableview

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, uilabel, didselectrowatindexpath

Might be a stupid question.

I have a UITableview, with multiple cells.  In each cell I am displaying some data. I am not using cell's text property to display data. Instead I have a custom label inside my cell, which is displaying the text. 
My question is:
When I click on the cell, I need to retrieve the data from the cell. How can I do this.

```
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];


    UILabel *CellTextlabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    CellTextlabel.tag = 222;
    [CellTextlabel setFrame:CGRectMake(40, 5, 200, 20)];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:CellTextlabel];
    [CellTextlabel release];
  }


UILabel *editCellTextlabel = (UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:222];
editCellTextlabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:18];
editCellTextlabel.text = contact.lastName;
```

Comment: Post the code you use to fill the cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could get access to that label in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` with

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
UILabel *myLabel = [cell.contentView viewWithTag:222];
```

But probably worth asking, why are you adding a sub label instead of using the `textLabel` property? you can modify its frame, settings etc and then you don't have to worry about tags, since this property is exposed in `UITableViewCell` by default

Comment: I just had some problem as I had more things to show in my cell. And me being a starter couldn't handle the alignment part without adding more labels and buttons instead of utilising cells text property and accessoryview etc

Comment: Instead of using viewWithTag I would subclass UITableViewCell and expose your data through properties - it would make your code a little more readable.

Comment: if you have more than just one label, i agree with @deanWombourne, you should subclass the UITableViewCell and add all the properties there. You can initialise in the cells init method, and set the frame of each sub view in layoutSubviews

Answer (score 2):

In your didSelectRowAtIndexPath method, you may do it as follows:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[self.tableViecellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];         
UILabel *textLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:222];
```

Now you can retrieve the data in the cell's UILabel using textLabel.text

Answer (score 1):

In the `-tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` method, you can get the data from your tableView's array:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    id objectForCell = [self.myArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    //do what you want with the above data.
}
```